# export utf-8 data to text file with oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to export urf-8 data to a text file in form of insert statement. I've tried Oracle SQL developer's export data tool. But it use ansi encoding to export data to txt file so utf-8 characters turn to "?" mark. I wonder how whether it's possible to use utf-8 encoding to export data ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export data in UTF-8 with Sql Developer. Make sure your [client NLS parameters are setup correctly](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306%5F01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#sthref185). If you're on windows these settings are in the registry. Make sure also that in the settings panel of Sql Developer you have selected UTF-8 as the encoding character set.

#### See Also

> [Oracle Unicode Spooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749337/oracle-unicode-spooling)