# SQL*Plus SPOOL on the windows command line

Tags: bash, unix, encoding, command-line, sqlplus

I have a problem with the command `SPOOL` of SQL*Plus executed on an UNIX system...

Before connecting to the database with SQL*Plus, I do an :

```
export NLS_LANG=french_FRANCE.UTF8
```

Then :

```
spool EXCEPTION.csv
select MY_COLUMN||';'||EXCEPTION_MESSAGE from TABLE_EXCEPTION;
spool off
```

When I open `EXCEPTION.csv` with Notepad++ on Windows :

```
ORA-01403: aucune donnée trouvée
```

It's what I expected, but with Microsoft Excel :

```
ORA-01403: aucune donnÃ©e trouvÃ©e
```

So, is it possible to `SPOOL` to the command line with SQL*Plus, without having to make an `unix2dos EXCEPTION.csv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an encoding problem.

First you can try to set encoding in spool part. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749337/oracle-unicode-spooling).

Second you can try to choose correct encoding in Text Import wizard.
That is instead of double clicking file name.

1. Open blank excel sheet
2. Choose Data Tab
3. Choose Import txt file.
4. Choose correct encoding

[image: Import Text]
[image: Text Import Wizard]

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to define the file encoding during the spool ?

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is also done via FTP. So, in addition to the above (edit: below), behold the option to copy as ASCII/TEXT or BINARY. These 2 methods should end up with different files. Optionally, your FTP tool can also use additional text conversion options, which are done when using ASCII/TEXT method.