# Compare stored procedure in SQL Developer - set NLS_CHARACTERSET for match accent marks

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer for compare a stored procedure (*from the database*) with a .sql file. This stored procedure and .sql file has *spanish mark accents*.

I do this comparasion using SQL Developer, by following these steps:

- Right-click on the body of the stored procedured from the database.
- select *`compare`* option.
- select *`with other file`* option.

The problem I'm facing is that both (*the stored procedure from the database AND the .sql file*) has *accent marks in spanish*:

Example:

```
UPDATE T_BH_ADMIN_COM_LOAD 
SET T_COBSERVATION = 'Observación debe contener mínimo 10 caracteres' 
WHERE NVL(TRIM(OBSERVACION), '') IS NOT NULL 
AND LENGTH(TRIM(OBSERVACION)) < 10
AND TRIM(ACL_COBSERVATION) IS NULL;
```

Where:

```
Observación debe contener mínimo 10 caracteres
```

Translated:

```
Observation must have minimum 10 characters
```

When I select the compare feature from SQL Developer, I got these results:

*Spanish mark accents shows interrogation mark in compare window result:*

[image: Spanish mark accents shows interrogation mark in compare window result]

When I execute this query I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749681/12511801):

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

The results are:

| PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| NLS_CHARACTERSET | WE8ISO8859P1 |

I wondering how I can compare the files using SQL Developer and avoiding the encoding differences.

I share the "SQL Developer about" information:

```
Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3.20
 Versión 4.1.3.20
Versión Interna MAIN-20.78

IDE Version: 12.2.1.0.42.151001.0541
Product ID: oracle.sqldeveloper
Product Version: 12.2.0.20.78

Versión
-------

Componente  Versión
==========  =======
Oracle IDE  4.1.3.20.78
Plataforma Java(TM) 1.8.0_60
Soporte de Control de Versiones 4.1.3.20.78
```

*NLS Preferences in SQL Developer:*

[image: NLS Preferences in SQL Developer]

For now, I'm using other tool for compare files - using Visual Studio built-in feature for compare files - [link to the answer with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664677/12511801), in this case, I have to copy/paste the results in plain text files and execute this feature, but, those are extra steps I want to avoid in the near future.

Is there anything I can do for use the compare feature from SQL Developer as I intend?

Comment: for starters, your version of SQLDev is very very very old. What's the file encoding in your pls file set to?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith can you tell me please how can I check the encoding of the pls file?