# Very slow query using FROM DUAL UNION ALL in a CTE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer for find the issue with the data that the MERGE statement raises the `ORA-30926` error.

> ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

The problem I have is that this issue is happening on production server and we don't have insert privileges - we can *only* query the data.

So, I decide to use CTEs for build the sub-query *"with the data the table used by the MERGE statement"*.

The CTE is as follows:

```
WITH SAMPLE_TABL
AS
(
SELECT 8 IIY_CODEN, '1016755' NUM_DCSM, 1 RW_NSKD FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 IIY_CODEN, '30029' NUM_DCSM, 1 RW_NSKD FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 IIY_CODEN, '21652019' NUM_DCSM, 1 RW_NSKD FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 IIY_CODEN, '10038' NUM_DCSM, 1 RW_NSKD FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 IIY_CODEN, '110004567448' NUM_DCSM, 1 RW_NSKD FROM DUAL
[...] -- 32706 rows 
)
SELECT T1.* 
FROM SAMPLE_TABL T1;
```

> I'm constructing this sub-query for emulate the content of a table
> that is used on a `MERGE` statement that raises the ORA-30926 error.
>
> With this result of the sub-query, I then run the `SELECT` that is
> used on the `MERGE` statement and export such results. Then, I can
> check which are the duplicated rows.
>
> The `SELECT` used in the `MERGE` has already a `DISTINCT` keyword on
> it, so, I'm narrow it down to steps for see the data that is executed
> on that specific `MERGE`.
>
> The information that is used on the CTE was supplied by the customer
> on a Excel file, so, I had to create the CTE in this way.
>
> **NOTE**: *If anyone know alternative(s) about how this issue can be handled, I'm open to suggestions.*

This CTE has 32706 rows and, testing in a different database, the query completes ***after 12 minutes***.

I tried this query on production and I have to cancel the query ***after 24 minutes*** and the cancellation took another more minutes.

I suspect this "result" is due to oracle/sql developer limitations in GUI or probably the database engine itself, but, I really don't know how then I can have a running sub-query with these 32K rows in order to check further the cause of the `ORA-30926` error.

These are the details of the SQL Developer instance I'm using - and I know that according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941118/compare-stored-procedure-in-sql-developer-set-nls-characterset-for-match-accen#comment120087341_67941118), this SQL Developer version is *very old*, but, that's what I got for work.

```
About
---------

Oracle SQL Developer 17.2.0.188
 Versión 17.2.0.188
Versión Interna 188.1159

IDE Version: 13.0.0.1.42.170225.0201
Product ID: oracle.sqldeveloper
Product Version: 17.2.0.188.1159

Versión
-------

Componente  Versión
==========  =======
Oracle IDE  17.2.0.188.1159
Plataforma Java(TM) 1.8.0_131
Soporte de Control de Versiones 17.2.0.188.1159
```

I narrow this question as down to:

> How I can have a running and working sub-query with 32K rows?

Comment: What's the goal here? Why are you constructing this 32,706-row query result?

Comment: I'm constructing this sub-query for emulate the content of a table that is used on a MERGE statement that raises the `ORA-30926` error. With this result of the sub-query, I then run the SELECT that is used on the MERGE statement and export such results. Then, I can check which are the duplicated rows. The SELECT used in the MERGE has already a DISTINCT, so, I'm narrow it down to steps for see the data that is executed on that specific MERGE.

Comment: Why can't you just query the actual table that is used in the merge?

Comment: @AlexPoole the actual table is empty and the 32K rows was provided by the customer in an excel file...

Comment: Use either global temporary tables or bind collections. Moreover in case of Excel(it stores data as xml), it's much easier to bind it as `XMLtype` and use it with `xmltable()`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov thanks for your comment. About the global temporary, we don't have those privileges on production (*where the issue is*) and asking for such privileges is time-consuming; about the Excel, can you point me to a sample to follow, please?